# Data flow by distributed web and file server

Tags: http, request

location A: web server
location B: file server

location A and B connected via DSL.

User in location B selects a PDF document linked from a webpage served from web server in location A. Will the PDF document be upload from loc. B to loc. A and then back transmitted to loc. B to the user which requested the document?

Or is it possible that the requested document will be directly sent to the browser of the user located in location B without transfering the PDF document from location B to location A and then back to location B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible in a fully transparent way in your case. While there are ways to do that (using LVS), it requires that all nodes are on the same layer 3 network, which is not the case in your setup.

What could be done in your case is that the webserver detects that the current user is actually in location B and doesn't send the document directly, but a HTTP 302 redirect which points to the document on the fileserver in location B. This would require that the user has direct access to the files there.

Alternatively, you could play with your DNS settings and mimic a CDN so that requests from location B to a hostname go to a different server than requests from location A.